# Finding anagrams in Python

Tags: python

I solved this problem the following way in Python:

```
s1,s2 = raw_input().split()
set1 = set(s1)
set2 = set(s2)
diff = len(set1.intersection(s2))
if(diff == 0)
    print "Anagram!" 
else:
    print "Not Anagram!"
```

It seemed fine to me. But my professor's program said I'm missing some edge cases. Can you think of any edge cases I might have missed?

Comment: Try, `aab` and `abb`

Comment: Using `sort` might be better

Comment: Basically according to @thefourtheye, the edge cases you are missing is when the words contain duplicates. So your algorithm will report a false positive for similar inputs

Comment: @thefourtheye Ooooooooooh. Thanks. I feel dumb for not seeing it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to solve this would be to count the number of characters in both the strings and comparing each of them to see if all the characters are the same and their counts are the same.

Python has a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to do this job for you. So, you can simply do

```
from collections import Counter

if Counter(s1) == Counter(s2):
    print "Anagram!" 
else:
    print "Not Anagram!"
```

If you don't want to use `Counter`, you can roll your own version of it, with normal dictionaries and then compare them.

```
def get_frequency(input_string):
    result = {}
    for char in input_string:
        result[char] = result.get(char, 0) + 1
    return result

if get_frequency(s1) == get_frequency(s2):
    print "Anagram!" 
else:
    print "Not Anagram!"
```

Comment: You can also emulate `Counter` with a dictionary comprehension: `counter = {char: input_str.count(char) for char in set(input_str)}`

Answer (score 2):

use sorted :

```
>>> def using_sorted(s1,s2):
...     return sorted(s1)==sorted(s2)
... 
>>> using_sorted("hello","llho")
False
>>> using_sorted("hello","llhoe")
True
```

you can also use `count`:

```
>>> def using_count(s1,s2):
...     if len(s1)==len(s2):
...         for x in s1:
...             if s1.count(x)!=s2.count(x):
...                 return False
...         return True
...     else: return False
... 
>>> using_count("abb","ab")
False
>>> using_count("abb","bab")
True
>>> using_count("hello","llohe")
True
>>> using_count("hello","llohe")
```

`sorted` solution runs in `O(n lg n)` complexity and the `count` solution runs in `O(n ^ 2)` complexity, whereas the `Counter` solution in runs in `O(N).`

Note `collections.Counter` is better to use
check @fourtheye solution

Comment: `sorted` solution runs in O(n lg n) complexity and the `count` solution runs in O(n ^ 2) complexity, whereas the `Counter` solution in my answer runs in O(N).

Comment: @thefourtheye i know about counter, you have already given that so there is no point in answer the samething, so i just given a way, i know its not good

Comment: That's fine :), that comment is to let the new users understand the importance of the `Counter` solution. Since `sorted` is easily understood, many people would not think about other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Another way without sorting considering all are alphabets:

```
>>> def anagram(s1, s2):
...     return sum([ord(x)**2 for x in s1]) == sum([ord(x)**2 for x in s2])
...
>>> anagram('ark', 'day')
False
>>> anagram('abcdef', 'bdefa')
False
>>> anagram('abcdef', 'bcdefa')
True
>>>
```

Comment: i think its one of the fastest method to determine anagram. +1

Comment: This won't work; it will say that `ark` and `day` are anagrams, even though they're not.

Comment: Now try `add` and `ebb`.  If you think it through, you should see why this approach is going to have a tough time working.

Comment: i think we can fix those by increasing the power to some large number.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it with set Theory:

Code:

```
a='aaab'
b='aab'

def anagram(a,b):
        setA=list(a)
        setB=list(b)
        print setA, setB
        if len(setA) !=len(setB):
                print "no anagram"
        diff1 =''.join(sorted(setA))
        diff2= ''.join(sorted(setB))
        if (diff1 == diff2 ):
                print "matched"
        else:
                print "Mismatched"
anagram(a,b)
```

Answer (score 0):

## the anagram check with two strings

```
def anagrams (s1, s2): 
  
    # the sorted strings are checked  
    if(sorted(s1.lower())== sorted(s2.lower())): 
        return True  
    else: 
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

check anagram in one liner

```
def anagram_checker(str1, str2):
    """
    Check if the input strings are anagrams of each other
    Args:
       str1(string),str2(string): Strings to be checked
    Returns:
       bool: Indicates whether strings are anagrams
    """
    return sorted(str1.replace(" ", "").lower()) == sorted(str2.replace(" ", "").lower())
```

`print(anagram_checker(" XYZ","z y x"))`